# Rendering show template with Responders gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, responders

So my question is how to render the show template only if the entity belongs to the current user. I have this code in my controller

```
 def show
   respond_with(@site) if current_user.author_of?(@site)
 end
```

But it still renders the show template. What is the right approach?

@site is this one

```
def find_site
  @site = Site.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to put this logic is within the `find_site` method.

Scope the query to the user. Assuming your relationship is `user has_many sites`, the following code will work:

`@site = current_user.sites.find(params[:id])`